# Integration problem Between reactnative app and Django server

Tags: django, react-native, file-upload, server, integration

When i run the server it shows me a message http://127.0.0.1:8000/. i want to do integration so i need to use this url in reactnative or anyother?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `axios` in your frontend app to create POST, GET or UPDATE requests using the url `http://localhost:8000/your_endpoint_name`. create your endpoints in the backend and go on.

Here is a link to axios library https://axios-http.com/

Happy coding !

Regarding your question I will add the code here to be more visible

Yes you will use the formData object in react to get the image as a file and pass to axios to send it to the backend. As this =>

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file",image)
formData.append("image", imagefile.files[0]);
axios.post('upload_file', formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
})
```

Comment: when i will use axios to send image from front-end then in backend do i have to write any code for getting the image? or it will auto? and then how to get reponse of that image after uploading

Comment: I added the answer to the post with an example of the code to send image from react to backend

Comment: Thanks, i have done the same way you told me, do i have to do anything in backend too? or just write the code in react native and image will go

Comment: You have to setup the backend endpoints and setup your server as a whole